# CMake: check for standard library file using CheckIncludeFileCXX

Tags: c++, cmake

I am trying to figure out if the current compiler supports `std::format`, however the following code is populating the variable `CXX_FORMAT_SUPPORT` with nothing. I assume I may need to add an include path, but I'm not sure how to get that for the compiler if that is the case.

```
# check std::format support
include(CheckIncludeFileCXX)
check_include_file_cxx("format" CXX_FORMAT_SUPPORT)
message(STATUS "CXX_FORMAT_SUPPORT: ${CXX_FORMAT_SUPPORT}")
```

How can I correctly populate `CXX_FORMAT_SUPPORT`?

Comment: your code works for me and reports `1` on visual studio 2019. Changing `"format"` to something that doesn't exist results in `CXX_FORMAT_SUPPORT` being empty. Are you sure your compiler has an include for `format`? Note that as `CXX_FORMAT_SUPPORT` is a cache variable you might need to clear the cache before `check_include_file_cxx` will run again

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood the function. I am on GCC and definitely do NOT have format support. I was expecting a 0, but clearly an empty string represents "not found" and 1 represents found. Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/CheckIncludeFileCXX.html) is less than clear but `check_include_file_cxx` sets the output variable to `1` if the header is found and doesn't set the variable if it is not found.